# Cassandra schema advice needed

Tags: cassandra, schema, bigdata

I'm designing a Cassandra schema for a browser event collection system, and I was hoping to sanity check my approach. The system collects user events in the browser, like mouse movements, clicks, etc. The events are stored and processed to create heat maps of user activity on a web page. I've chosen Cassandra for persistence, since my use case is more write  heavy than ready heavy: every 50 milliseconds, an ajax call dumps the aggregated events to my server, and into the database. I'm using node.js for the server, and the JSON events look something like this on the server:

```
{ uuid: dsf86ag487hadf97hadf97, type: 'MOVE', time: 12335234345, pageX: 334, pageY:566, .... }
```

As you can see each user has a unique uuid, associated with each of their events, generated on the browser, stored in a cookie. My read case will be some map-reduce job. Each top-level domain will be a keyspace, and I was planning using the uuid as my partition key. The main table will be the events table, where each row will be one event, using a composite primary key, consisting of the browser-generated uuid and a cassandra-generated timeuuid. The primary key must have a timeuuid component, since two events may have the same timestamp on certain browsers. The data types for event will be strings, ints, timestamps. The total data for a partition should not exceed a few hundred megabytes. So...Is this sane? What questions should I be asking myself? I recognize that this use case has many analogs in sensor data collection, etc, so please point me to existing examples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

### Choosing a partition key

While recording the user ID may be important in some cases for distinguishing events from different users that may occur at the same time, the user ID is probably not the best choice for the partition key.  That is, unless you are planning to analyze the behavior of *specific* users.

You are probably more concerned with how the heatmap changes *over time* and specifically *which areas* of the page were involved.  These are probably better considerations for your partition key, though perhaps not stored as a timestamp nor as X/Y coordinates, which I'll get into later.

You will generally want to choose a partition key that has (1) a large distribution of values, to create even load across your cluster, and (2) is made up of values that are relatively "well known".  By "well known", I mean something you either know in advance or something that can be computed easily and deterministically.  For instance, you will have many users and will gather statistics over many days.  While the the specific of days (encoded as, say, YYYY-MM-DD strings) can be easily determined based on a known start/end date range or query input, the set of all valid user IDs (assuming UUIDs or other non-incremental value, or hash) is much harder to determine without doing a scan of the entire cluster.  Avoid doing partition key scans; aim for "exact" random access to your partitions.

### Format of the partition key

The partition key is traditionally shown as a single column in many examples, but you *can* have a multi-column partition key.  This can be useful when using date/time information as all or part of the key.  You would aim to have as few unique values per column as possible, so that the set of values you need to enumerate is as small as possible, but as many values (or additional columns) as necessary to balance the I/O load and data distribution across the cluster.

For example, if you were to use a timestamp as your partition key, in 64-bit Java timestamp format, there are 1,000 possible partitions *per second*.  Even though you can technically iterate over them, that may be more granular than you need or want.  On the other side, if your partition key were simply the 4-digit year, then *all* of that year's events would go to the same partition (making it very large) and to the same set of replica nodes (hotspots, inefficient cluster use).  By choosing a key that balances between these extremes, you can control the size of your partitions and also the number of partitions you must access in order to satisfy a query.

Also consider what you'll do when you ever want to delete old data.  The easiest means (within a single column family/table) is to delete an entire partition as this helps avoid accumulating individual column *tombstones*.  If you ever want to run an operation like "delete all data older than 2013" then you definitely *don't* want to bury the date deep down in the data and would rather have it as part of your partition key.

## Choosing a row (clustering) key

Any additional columns in the primary key that are *not* part of the partition key become the row key within the partition, and the rows are *clustered* (ordered) by the sort order of the first of these columns.

That clustering/sorting is important, because it's generally the only native sorting you're going to get with Cassandra.  Even if the partition key is down to the level of a specific hour or minute of a specific day, you might choose to cluster the rows by your millisecond timestamp or time UUID, to keep everything within that partition in chronological order.

You can still have additional columns, like your X/Y coordinates or user IDs, in your row keys -- in case it sounded like I was recommending that you put time (only) in *both* the partition and clustering keys.

## Using X/Y coordinates

This part has nothing to do with Cassandra, but if you're heat-mapping the page, do be aware that people use different screens and devices at different resolutions.  Unless you're doing pixel-perfect layout on your site (and hopefully you're using a fluid, responsive layout instead) then the X/Y coordinate of one user isn't going to match the X/Y coordinates from another user.  They might not even match for the same user, if that user switches devices.

Consider mapping not by X/Y coordinate of the mouse, but perhaps the IDs of elements in the DOM.  Have an ID for your "sidebar", "main menu", "main body div" and any specific elements you want to map.  These would be string keys, not coordinate pairs, and while they'd still be triggered on mouse enter/leave/click the logged information doesn't depend or assume any particular screen geometry.

Perhaps you decide to include the element ID as part of the row or partition key, too.